# ASP.NET MVC4 - JQuery jqFancyTransitions error: TypeError: $(...).jqFancyTransitions is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my Index.cshtml view, and for some reason, the JQuery is having a hard time firing the jqFancyTransitions method (it's acting as if the jqFancyTransitions library isn't included).  The JavaScript **IS** firing though.  For testing, I even put `$('#rotatingImages').html('blah');` to see if it would find my ID and replace it's HTML contents, but it didn't.

I do get a JS error in my Firebug console: `TypeError: $(...).jqFancyTransitions is not a function`.  Yet, I get jqFancyTransitions intellisense after I type a dot at the end of the parenthesis.

EDIT:

The jqFancyTransitions.js library **IS** in fact being loaded into the browser according to Firebug.  To test it out, I removed the reference to it, and then I didn't see the library was loaded.  I added it back in to my view, and I see it.

Here's the code on Index.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rotatingImages').jqFancyTransitions({
            effect: 'wave', // wave, zipper, curtain
            width: 959, // width of panel
            height: 300, // height of panel
            strips: 20, // number of strips
            delay: 4000, // delay between images in ms
            stripDelay: 50, // delay beetwen strips in ms
            titleOpacity: 0.7, // opacity of title
            titleSpeed: 1000, // speed of title appereance in ms
            position: 'alternate', // top, bottom, alternate, curtain
            direction: 'fountainAlternate', // left, right, alternate, random, fountain, fountainAlternate
            navigation: false, // prev and next navigation buttons
            links: false // show images as links
        });

        // $('#rotatingImages').html('blah'); // just for testing
    });
</script>

<div id="rotatingImages">
    <img src="Images/Background/bg1.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/Background/bg2.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/Background/bg3.jpg" />
    <img src="Images/Background/bg4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Are those by chance ASP controls..?

Comment: No, they aren't... they're just regular HTML controls.  I briefly thought of ClientIDMode, but I remembered that is only available on ASP controls, and only used when doing document.getElementById.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Good catch... I didn't think to check the console.  I get "TypeError: $(...).jqFancyTransitions is not a function".  I will investigate.  I guess the JS isn't even getting into this function.

Comment: I think the problem is you're not referencing jQuery. You import the plugin, not jQ.

Comment: Paste this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` above your script.

Comment: I'll try that, but jquery is referenced in the _Layout.cshtml.  I can do a basic $(document).ready(function() { alert('test') }); and it will alert.

Comment: No that didn't do it.  I even get intellisense when I type a dot after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Try `$('').jqFancyTransitions`. If it doesn't return 'function', maybe your jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js call is returning 404 from the browser but not from the IDE (as you said IntelliSense was working).

Comment: @Seza I did that and same error

Comment: Inspect your code (via chrome, for example): press F12, and in the Elements tab, look up for the jqFancyTransitions js call, right-button the link which opens up the script, select "Copy Link Address", paste it in another browser tab and see if the script was correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real simple.  All I had to do was include my scripts in a "scripts" section inside the view I was working in, which was Index.cshtml, as follows:

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fancyTransitions")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rotatingImages').jqFancyTransitions({
                effect: 'wave', // wave, zipper, curtain
                width: 959, // width of panel
                height: 300, // height of panel
                strips: 20, // number of strips
                delay: 4000, // delay between images in ms
                stripDelay: 50, // delay beetwen strips in ms
                titleOpacity: 0.7, // opacity of title
                titleSpeed: 1000, // speed of title appereance in ms
                position: 'alternate', // top, bottom, alternate, curtain
                direction: 'fountainAlternate', // left, right, alternate, random, fountain, fountainAlternate
                navigation: false, // prev and next navigation buttons
                links: false // show images as links
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your JavaScript reference needs to be changed to

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js")"></script>
```

for Razor ViewEngine, or

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js")%>"></script>
```

for WebForms ViewEngine.

Answer (score -1):

I thing u forgot to link jQuery library on the top. before

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js"> </script>
```

Comment: No I didn't, the jquery library is referenced in my master page, _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: Plus, it's recognizing the $ syntax which is JQuery, so the base JQuery library is loaded and working.